# Can i use variable inside another variable in ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

In my role i have `default.yml` like this

`site_root: "/var/www/html/sites"`

`project_root: "/var/www/html/sites/site1"`

Can i use like this

`project_root: "{{site_root }}/site1"`

I tried that but its not working

Comment: You have an extra space after `site_root ` which could be causing the issue.

Comment: spaces don't matter, @aziz-saleh. `{{foo}}` and `{{ foo }}` are both valid in Jinja2.

Answer (score 1):

This should definitely work. For example, the following playbook should print out the resolved project_root as you would expect it (when running the playbook use the **-v** flag to see the stdout of the echo command):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - site_root: "/var/www/html/sites"
    - project_root: "{{site_root}}/site1"
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{project_root}}
```

This also works when used in a role. Notice though that defining default variables for a role is done, not in default.yml, but rather in a main.yml file located under the **defaults** directory:

```
- 
|- roles
   |- <your_role_name>
      |- defaults
         |- main.yml
```

This works for ansible version > 1.5 (and probably for earlier versions as well)